# BizTalk Map with Multiple Output Messages

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper, biztalk-schemas

**I know it is possible to create a map that takes one input message and outputs multiple messages within an orchestration.**

When you do the reverse of this i.e. merge many messages into one.  The 'wizard' creates the map and the input schema.  However when doing the above only a map is created.  The schema is in-line.

Is there a way around this?  I would like to create my own output schema and map without spinning up an orchestration.  If I try to do this I am unable to assign multiple messages to the output **even if I copy the in-line schema structure from a generated map**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is - **Not Possible**.  When mapping to multiple output messages **the schema has to be in-line**.

Comment: If you want to create two output messages from one input message without a Orchestration, just have two send ports subscribing to the same message with a different map on each.  If you want it inside on orchestration, just run both maps.