# BizTalk - One to many transformation

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper, biztalk-orchestrations

With BizTalk Maps, there can be one to one transformations. A source schema can be added and a destination schema can be added.

How can one to many transformation occur? I want a received message to produce 2 different output messages.

I understand Orchestration can be used however is there a method by which this one to many transformation can be done without using Orchestration?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451843/biztalk-map-with-multiple-output-messages?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, I came across that. With version changes since then, I wonder if there have been changes to accommodate this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can setup a Multi-Output Map in the Orchestration Designer, do you really need to do this?

In most cases, it's just **easier to use two Maps**, A->B and A->C.

In the Orchestration, you can either use two Transform Shapes in sequence or in a Parallel Shape.  As the source Message, A, is unaltered (immutable), you can use it as many times as you need.

Comment: But, we can't use 2 maps on the same message, surely? An input message will either hit the map A->B or A->C. In my case I want it being A->B&C.

Comment: Make using of the publish/subscribe architecture: use 2 send ports. 
Put an outbound map on each of them and subscribe each send port to the incoming message.That way your incoming message will be routed to each send port, executing both mappings in the context of their own send port.